# Electric potential in point with current going in opposite directions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am having trouble with a specific assignment. I am supposed to find the electric potential at P. Normally this is no problem, however, there are two voltage sources that output a current that goes in opposite directions.

[image]

What I've figured is that the voltage going from the voltage source with no inner resistance and an electromotive force of 4.5V is greater than the voltage from the one with an inner resistance of 0.5Ω, due to

```
4.5V > (4.5 - 0.5*I)
```

So the current would be going from the "top voltage source" to the bottom one, or am I wrong? I would like some guidance in how I can solve this, since this is not the area I am the best at to put it lightly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use the principle of superposition then you must consider the whole of the relevant circuit not just part of it.

[image]

So the bottom two circuit diagram will show you that the currents in those two circuits are of the same magnitude and opposite in direction.

What you did is compare the potential differences between nodes $P$ and $Q$ and between nodes $R$ and $S$.

Having found the (total) current in the loop you can now find the potential of node $P$ relative to the node which I assume is at zero potential, to the left of the negative terminal of the $2\,\rm V$ cell.

To do that start at the zero of potential and "walk" to the node whose potential you wish to find adding/subtracting the voltages whilst applying the following convention:

- If you walk through a voltage source from the negative terminal to
  the positive terminal add the voltage of the voltage source otherwise
  subtract the voltage.
- If you walk through a resistor in the same direction as the direction
  of current flow subtract the voltage across the resistor, $IR$,
  otherwise add the voltage.

As a check walk around the circuit along another path and you should get the same value of node potential, ie walk from the node at zero potential to node $Q$ and then node $P$ as one route and then go from the zero of potential along route $RSP$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am still confused as to how to calculate the total current of the circuit. We can replace the two 4Ω resistors with one 2Ω resistor, and the 0.5Ω internal resistance and 10Ω resistor with one 10.5Ω resistor. But from here I am uncertain of what to do, should I just add the 10.5Ω and 2Ω resistors together in series, parallel or something else?

Comment: What is total emf in the circuit with two 4.5 V cells?

Comment: Should it be 9V plus the 2V cell near the ground?

Comment: Work out the currents (with direction) of the two circuits below yours and then add those currents to find the current in your circuit.

Comment: So that makes it 0A? Since you would have one current of 0.36A in one direction and 0.36A in the other direction would they both cancel out?

Comment: I leave it to you to solve your problem and consider how you might have done it without using superposition.